# Selenium WebDriver Java: Convert Expression to Lambda

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, lambda

I'm looking for a way to write this block using lambda:

```
public void waitUntilElemIsDisabled(WebElement element) {
        try {
            wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return !element.isEnabled();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

I was trying out `wait.until(e -> element.isEnabled());` but I'm getting a syntax error:

```
The method until(Predicate<WebDriver>) is ambiguous for the type FluentWait<WebDriver>
```

If it helps, here's how I initialized `wait`:

```
wait = new FluentWait<>(webDriver).withTimeout(impTimeout, s).pollingEvery(pollingMsInt, ms)
                    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

I'm fairly new at using lambda, currently following [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html) guide but I can't find a pattern that matches the one i'm using.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you might be using the deprecated `until()` method. Take a look at this [somewhat related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42421762/1183506)

Comment: I often use the IDE's refactoring ability as a substitute for using my brain to solve such things.  In IntelliJ, I would click on the lambda, use Refactor/Extract to Value, correct the type parameters if needed, then use Refactor/Inline to integrate the value back in to the original expression.  Usually, it will automatically add any needed casts or explicit type parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work this out.

Solution:

```
private Function<WebDriver, Boolean> webElemBooleanFunction(boolean condition) {
    return x -> condition;
}
```

Invoke using:

```
public void waitUntilFieldIsPopulated(WebElement element) {
    try {
        wait.until(webElemBooleanFunction(getElementValue(element).length() > 0));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Thanks for the tips!