# until in FluentWait cannot be applied - java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I've had a helper class for Selenium that worked like a charm previously, and out of the blue, this issue came up.

I've also attached a screenshot of the affected functions.

until
(java.util.function.Function)
in FluentWait cannot be applied
to
(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition)
 
 reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) V exist so that ExpectedCondition conforms to Function

[image]

Comment: None of the waits are FluentWait here in your code. These are types of ExplicitWait. Make the correction in your Question Subject & Question body.

Comment: @Dev That's the error that Intellij  is throwing.

Comment: Observe the documentation of ExplicitWait here - http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: @Dev Thank you for the added reference, however the issue hasn't been resolved.

Comment: What are the steps you want to perform? What worked for you till now? Show your code. Where are you exactly stuck?

Comment: @Dev the test case is supposed to wait for a clickable button for signing up users to complete. but that doesn't happen because the class throws error I suppose. it used to work before but not anymore.

The registration is a three phase pages and each page there's a continue button that validates server side(ajax call) and I also call this explicit wait function to tell it to wait before clicking on each page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142401/discussion-between-dev-and-mohamed-hesham).

Comment: @Dev `WebDriverWait` extends `FluentWait`. See the docs. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wait.until(ExpectedConditions) doesnt work any more in selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421148/wait-untilexpectedconditions-doesnt-work-any-more-in-selenium)

Comment: It's always a good practice to google the error that you get before posting an question. It's extremely unlikely that you are the first to get said error message and it saves everyone time having to answer a question that has already been answered.

Comment: @JeffC Thank you for your link as well as your downvote, I never ask on here before I google the error I have, try googling it first and if you came up with solutions let me know.

And as someone who is new to Selenium I had to ask here, and I guess that's why Stackoverflow is for?

Comment: I did google it and the first result was the question that I dup'd this to. If you did google it, you should put some of the things you tried so we don't have to guess what all you have tried or if you tried anything. This is all covered in [ask].

Comment: @Dev is not familiar with Selenium, perhaps, and isn't aware it isn't your own library but a very common third party one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to update the jre used by Intellij. that resolved the issue.

Update: Google Guava 23.0 also fixed the issue for some people.

Comment: This worked for me. using 1.8 resolved the IJ complaint.

Comment: None of the proposed solutions made the job.
Still looking for a solution

Answer (score 2):

Just use the following in your `pom.xml`

```
<build>
   <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
   </plugins>        
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case  previously I was using the below one in `pom.xml`

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
     <version>3.141.59</version>
 </dependency>
```

I removed the above one and replaced with this

```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.1</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
```

It worked and "until(java.util.function.Function) in FluentWait cannot be applied to" this error gone from my IntelliJ class.

```
Something is deprecated or not working in newer selenium jar version. so use old one.
You can also add following dependency specifically in pom.xml and check.
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```