# ExpectedConditions won't work after Selenium update

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I always used the following piece of java code to tell my Selenium Webdriver tests to wait a certain amount of time as specified within my config file (waittime is time wait for an element to be present in seconds).

```
private void waitForElementPresent(By locator) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Integer.parseInt(CONFIG.getProperty("waittime")));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
```

It always worked fine, until I updated after 2.47.1.

What I want, is that this helper code works once more under the new webdriver versions.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If I will talk about selenium 3.12.0 , I have not faced this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[until in FluentWait cannot be applied - java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571319/until-in-fluentwait-cannot-be-applied-java) had the same issue. I wasn't able to find this, as I was under the impression I had an Explicit wait, but it was a fluent wait. Searching on Fluent wait I found the solution.

Dependency Google Guava had to be upgraded alongside Webdriver. Once I updated com.google.guava to 23.0 it worked like a charm.