# In Selenium 4 and above versions wait.until throws java: method until in class org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait<T> cannot be applied

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium4

I used

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(60));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Home"))));
```

But in wait.until line it throws below error when running the code.

> java: method until in class
> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait cannot be applied to
> given types;   required: java.util.function.Function<? super
> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver,V>   found:
> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement>
> reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) V
> (argument mismatch; org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement>
> cannot be converted to java.util.function.Function<? super
> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver,V>)

I tried all the solutions in [until in FluentWait cannot be applied - java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571319/until-in-fluentwait-cannot-be-applied-java) but no avail. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case,  when I update selenium-firefox-driver as below solved the issue.
Earlier, I had 3.141.59.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```