# wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(userName)) is not working

Tags: java, selenium

In the below code on 33rd line getting below error message near wait.until

Multiple markers at this line
    - The type com.google.common.base.Function cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    - The method until(Function) in the type FluentWait is not applicable for the 
     arguments (ExpectedCondition)

```
   package MPA;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class LoginhelperClass {

    WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@ng-model='login.username']")
    private WebElement userName;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='password']")
    private WebElement Password;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='submit' and @value='Sign In']")
    private WebElement SignIn;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[@class='icon-avatar-round']")
    private WebElement Avatar;

    public LoginhelperClass(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void logIn(String uName, String Pswd) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,7);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(userName));
        userName.sendKeys(uName);
        Password.sendKeys(Pswd);
        SignIn.click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            if (Avatar.isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("Login Successfull: " + uName);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Login failure check the credentials: " + uName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}




 package MPA;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class LoginhelperClass {

    WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@ng-model='login.username']")
    private WebElement userName;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='password']")
    private WebElement Password;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='submit' and @value='Sign In']")
    private WebElement SignIn;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[@class='icon-avatar-round']")
    private WebElement Avatar;

    public LoginhelperClass(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void logIn(String uName, String Pswd) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,7);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(userName));
        userName.sendKeys(uName);
        Password.sendKeys(Pswd);
        SignIn.click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            if (Avatar.isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("Login Successfull: " + uName);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Login failure check the credentials: " + uName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are using maven, then do a clean install to fix all project imports.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wait.until(ExpectedConditions) doesnt work any more in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421148/wait-untilexpectedconditions-doesnt-work-any-more-in-selenium)

Comment: What can be that `33rd line` all about?

Answer (score 1):

The error which you are seeing is as follows :

```
Multiple markers at this line - The type com.google.common.base.Function cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files - The method until(Function) in the type FluentWait is not applicable for the arguments (ExpectedCondition)
```

Let us analyze what is happening in our code.

In the `Page Object` you have defined an `WebElement` as :

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@ng-model='login.username']")
private WebElement userName;
```

Moving ahead you have tried to use the `WebElement` within the method :

```
public void logIn(String uName, String Pswd) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,7);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(userName));
    //
}
```

So basically here we were trying to wait for the visibility of an **Indirectly Referenced** **`Angular WebElement`** **userName** which is dependent on the attribute **`ng-model`**. In such circumstances we can never be sure that when the `WebElement` will be referenced within a method **userName** will mandatory reference to a **not NULL** value. It may be **`NULL`** as well.

Now let us have a look at the **Method Defination** of **`visibilityOf`**, it is defined as :

```
visibilityOf(WebElement element)
An expectation for checking that an element, known to be present on the DOM of a page, is visible.
```

So clearly, **`visibilityOf`** method expects a **Direct Reference** of the `WebElement`. Hence in absence of a definite value (**not NULL**) of **`userName`**, **`WebDriverWait`** which is a variant of **`FluentWait`** shows the error.

Comment: I am seeing same issue. what is weird is ..error is reproducible on Chrome but same code wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)); is working good on Firefox. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Play with conditions with By/WebElement:

```
ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By)
ExpectedConditions.elementExists(By)
ExpectedConditions.elementIsVisible(By)
ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By/WebElement)
ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By)
```