# Error on using WebDriverWait through ExpectedCondition method presenceOfElementLocated()

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I get error while compiling:

```
public static WebDriverWait wait = null; 
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(HomeScreen.tabHome_ID)));
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDE

**Error**

```
Error:(51, 19) java: method until in class org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait cannot be applied to given types;
required: java.util.function.Function<? super org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver,V>
found: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement>
reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) V
(argument mismatch; org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement> cannot be converted to java.util.function.Function<? super org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver,V>)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421148/wait-untilexpectedconditions-doesnt-work-any-more-in-selenium

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a problem with the JRE version. If you are using maven add this to the POM file to specify the Java version (you can change the `1.8` to whatever version you are using)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
   </plugins>        
</build>
```

You can also change it under **File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler**, in the **Target bytecode version** column.

Comment: There is no POM file in IntelliJ IDEA :(
But there is some .iml file in it, Is this a project/packages configuration file?

Comment: @MohsinAwan You can't do it (AFAIK) with the .iml file. I added another option to my answer.

Comment: Issue is with wait.until() method of wait. Can you please help me how to use the newer version of until() method or how to use the deprecated until() method?

Comment: @MohsinAwan Did you updated all the modules? Is it the same error?

Comment: Well in an old project it is working fine. I just made a new project & copied few basic files from the old project. Now it is showing this error!

Comment: @MohsinAwan This is not what I asked. Did you update the settings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168038/discussion-between-guy-and-mohsin-awan).