# NoSuchMethodError - WebDriverWait / Wait.until(Ljava/util/function/Function;)

Tags: java, ios, selenium-webdriver, testng, appium-ios

I am working on iDevices Automation using Mac book with macOS Sierra. I have came all the way and made real device automation successfully using appium. What happens now is 'NoSuchMethodError' is getting displayed. I have no idea why is throws that.

I am using:

1. Selenium WebDriver 3.9.1
2. Guava jar is 23.6 and updated to latest as well
3. JAVA_HOME is set properly and in eclipse also chosen the same
   version.

I am using TestNG for the test methods and just tried to run like 'Right Click --> Run as TestNG'.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421148/wait-untilexpectedconditions-doesnt-work-any-more-in-selenium

Comment: Please see my numbers. I have done those steps. Still facing the issue.
In addition, I tried guava jar manually with guava dependency. Then after removing that dependency, guava jar is not getting added under Maven depencencies by using seleniumhq. I am so confused. And please state which answer you are mentioning.

Comment: @Bala did you solve the problem? I'm facing the same issue, please help