# How to use ExpectedConditions in Selenium 4?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriverwait, selenium4

In selenium 4, you can wait for an element's presence but I am unable to find alternates if I want to wait for an element to become invisible or Clickable, or an alert to appear.
Following mentioned statements are not working in selenium 4 as this version of Until is deprecated

```java
if (KeyWord.contains("Visibility")) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)); // waiting for the element to be visible
} else if (KeyWord.contains("Click")) {                  
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)); // waiting for the element to be Clickable
} else if (KeyWord.contains("Frame")) {
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(element)); // waiting for the frame to be available and switch to it
} else if (KeyWord.contains("Invisibility")) {                   
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(element));
} else if (KeyWord.contains("Alert")) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question already has an answer here:
[wait.until(ExpectedConditions) doesnt work any more in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421148/wait-untilexpectedconditions-doesnt-work-any-more-in-selenium)
basically telling you to add (or upgrade your existing) Google Guava dependency.