# Maven dependency conflict caused by same class name in different artifacts

Tags: java, maven

My project depends on `javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1` and `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:3.1.0` which in turn depends on `jsr311-api:1.1.1`.

`My project
-> javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1
-> hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:3.1.0
   -> jsr311-api:1.1.1`

The problem is that class `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` is included in both `javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1` and `jsr311-api:1.1.1`, but they have different method signatures. When compiling the project, Maven tried to find the `readEntity(Class<T> entityType)` method in `jsr311-api` instead of `javax.ws.rs-api`, which caused `NoSuchMethodError`.

I solved this problem by excluding `jsr311-api` from dependency `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core`. But I want to understand why Maven tries to use `jsr311-api`? Is there a dependency classpath? How can I find it?

PS: I know the mechanism of Maven to resolve dependency conflict between different versions of the same artifact, but this problem is different.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740785/why-order-of-maven-dependencies-matter

Comment: That's interesting. So it sounds like the parent class' dependency is included on the classpath first. If you run `dependency:build-classpath`, it should generate the classpath from your dependencies. Try adding a removing the exclusion to see what it generates.