# Replace a transitive dependency building maven fat jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to replace a transitive dependency with a latest one while creating my fat jar. But every time the old dependency gets included in the jar. I have tried both assembly plugin as well as shade plugin. Here is snippet from my pom-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Shade plugin snippet-

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </artifactSet>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the `dependency:tree` command to see who's linking to the wrong version? That's the easiest way to track these things down. Then you can `exclude` the transitive dependency.

Comment: Yes, I did! Spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11 is adding that dependency but even after excluding the transitive dependency from this dependency the transitive dependency still gets packaged into the fat jar. I have already shown how I am doing it.

Comment: Please add the `dependency:tree` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try reordering the dependency.

Keep the dependency with the version you want on top of the dependency from where it is getting included through transitive dependency.

Do `mvn dependency:tree` a few times to get it right.

Example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <!-- <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions> -->
</dependency>
```

Ref:

```
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740785/why-order-of-maven-dependencies-matter
2. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies
```