# No ExecutorFactory found to execute the application in Flink 1.11.1

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

first of all I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63032060/upgraded-flink-from-1-10-to-1-11-met-error-no-executorfactory-found-to-execute) about the same issue and tried to follow the same solution that works for him (create a new quickstart with mvn and migrate the code there) and is not working eighter when out-of-the-box of IntelliJ.

Here is my pom.xml mixed with my dependencies from the other pom.xml. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>job</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>funnel-cep-analytics</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <flink.version>1.11.0</flink.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <log4j.version>2.12.1</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Apache Flink dependencies -->
        <!-- These dependencies are provided, because they should not be packaged into the JAR file. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add connector dependencies here. They must be in the default scope (compile). -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-runtime-web_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add connector dependencies here. They must be in the default scope (compile). -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-hadoop-fs</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-filesystem_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-metrics-prometheus -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-metrics-prometheus_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-rabbitmq_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.bahir</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-redis_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-cep_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-test-utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-test-utils_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-runtime_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add logging framework, to produce console output when running in the IDE. -->
        <!-- These dependencies are excluded from the application JAR by default. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-test-utils-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add logging framework, to produce console output when running in the IDE. -->
        <!-- These dependencies are excluded from the application JAR by default. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Java Compiler -->
            <!-- Java Compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- We use the maven-shade plugin to create a fat jar that contains all necessary dependencies. -->
            <!-- Change the value of <mainClass>...</mainClass> if your program entry point changes. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:force-shading</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                    Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>path.StreamingJob</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <!-- This improves the out-of-the-box experience in Eclipse by resolving some warnings. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>shade</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>add-dependencies-for-IDEA</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>idea.version</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${flink.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
                    <version>${flink.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
                    <version>${flink.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

and the error here when running out from IntelliJ:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ExecutorFactory found to execute the application.
        at org.apache.flink.core.execution.DefaultExecutorServiceLoader.getExecutorFactory(DefaultExecutorServiceLoader.java:84) ~[cep-1.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1803) ~[cep-1.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1713) ~[cep-1.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment.execute(LocalStreamEnvironment.java:74) ~[cep-1.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1699) ~[job.jar:?]
        at com.test.job.StreamingJob.runCEP(StreamingJob.java:122) ~[job.jar:?]
        at com.test.job.StreamingJob.init(StreamingJob.java:107) ~[job.jar:?]
        at com.test.job.StreamingJob.main(StreamingJob.java:64) [job.jar:?]
```

Comment: I'm using Local Environment configuration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For me below dependencies worked like a charm:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-core -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-scala -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: It's worked here. In my case (using Gradle) I just add the flink- clients 
'implementation("org.apache.flink:flink-clients:1.16.1")'

Answer (score 10):

You have `<scope>provided</scope>` in the below,

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

so remove `<scope>provided</scope>` it will work, i just tested in my local, works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Thangavel Loganathan, I think that I already try that and it was in vain but anyhow I will do it again, but when you create the quickstart with mvn from Flink repository that's the custom scope. Thanks one more time

Comment: Some times you need to modify them to work. Did you remove the scope and tried?

Comment: I did remove the scope and tried with `compile` too and nothing, the issue remains there. Already tried again and nothing,  I'm running out of ideas. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the problem was fixed by removing these two dependencies because client dependency has them already included.

```
        /*removed*/
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        /*removed*/
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        /*Keep just this one*/
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

The error appears when `flink-clients` is not in the classpath. Can you double-check if your profile is working as expected by inspecting the actual classpath? Btw for IntelliJ you don't need the profile at all. Just tick the option to include provided dependencies in the Run/Debug dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Update for Flink version 1.15.1, specifically for getting the [Table API](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/try-flink/table_api/) example working from the Flink docs.

- It needs adding the `flink-table-planner` as a provided dependency.
- The planner contains an implementation of the `ExecutorFactory`, called `org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.DefaultExecutorFactory`

Adding this solved it:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-table-planner_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @adamo, I will try myself when I reach that version of Flink.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Thangavel Loganathan

I'd remove the `<scope>provided</scope>` from the dependency and after `mvn clean package` I was able to see that the library is shaded to the jar as you can see here: `[INFO] Including org.apache.flink:flink-clients_2.11:jar:1.11.0 in the shaded jar.`, but even that I still having this issue when out of the box of IntelliJ:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ExecutorFactory found to execute the application.
        at org.apache.flink.core.execution.DefaultExecutorServiceLoader.getExecutorFactory(DefaultExecutorServiceLoader.java:84)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1803)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1713)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment.execute(LocalStreamEnvironment.java:74)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1699)
        at com.teavaro.cep.StreamingJob.runCEP(StreamingJob.java:129)
        at com.teavaro.cep.StreamingJob.prepareJob(StreamingJob.java:115)
        at com.teavaro.cep.StreamingJob.main(StreamingJob.java:69)
```

Here is how I have configured the dependencies in the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>quickstart</groupId>
    <artifactId>cep</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <flink.version>1.11.0</flink.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
        <pgbulkinsert.version>3.3</pgbulkinsert.version>
        <kda.version>1.0.1</kda.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <log4j.version>2.12.1</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
<dependencies>
        <!-- Apache Flink dependencies -->
        <!-- These dependencies are provided, because they should not be packaged into the JAR file. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>more dependencies here</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Java Compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- We use the maven-shade plugin to create a fat jar that contains all necessary dependencies. -->
            <!-- Change the value of <mainClass>...</mainClass> if your program entry point changes. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:force-shading</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                    Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>

                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>path.to.StreamingJob</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!-- This improves the out-of-the-box experience in Eclipse by resolving some warnings. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>shade</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <!-- This profile helps to make things run out of the box in IntelliJ -->
    <!-- Its adds Flink's core classes to the runtime class path. -->
    <!-- Otherwise they are missing in IntelliJ, because the dependency is 'provided' -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>add-dependencies-for-IDEA</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>idea.version</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${flink.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
                    <version>${flink.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
                    <version>${flink.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Then if I browse into the jar created I'm able to find the dependency under META-INF\maven\org.apache.flink:
[image]

Here is my job graph more or less:

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(parallelism, conf);
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Event> streamFiltered = RabbitMQConnector.eventStreamObject(env)
                .flatMap(new RMQConsumer())
                .name("Event Mapper")
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy.<Event>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(PropertyFileReader.getLatencyAllowed()))withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> event.timestamp.getTime()))
                .name("Watermarks Added")
                .filter(new NullIdEventsFilterFunction())
                .name("Event Filter");
/*more transformations here*/
env.execute("job name");
```

Kind regards!

Comment: Can you please put your code into gist/gihub? So that i can clone it and check it out. I just copied your pom and deleted all the artifacts and ran it. Works fine to me for a simple job.

Comment: Mean while ```Invalidate Cache/Restart``` your IntelliJ under File Menu?

Answer (score 1):

By reading [Flink Demo](https://github.com/apache/flink-playgrounds/blob/19ffc0e5af737ffa7bb5abb360142836f7030a10/docker/ops-playground-image/java/flink-playground-clickcountjob/pom.xml?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container%2C%20div%5Bitemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FSoftwareSourceCode%22%5D%20main%2C%20%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D#L199), you can see the problem solved.

Add this profile below your `pom.xml`.

```
<project>

.......

  <!-- This profile helps to make things run out of the box in IntelliJ -->
  <!-- Its adds Flink's core classes to the runtime class path. -->
  <!-- Otherwise they are missing in IntelliJ, because the dependency is 'provided' -->
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>add-dependencies-for-IDEA</id>

      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>idea.version</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
          <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
          <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
          <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
          <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
          <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
          <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but when you use a Planner, you will have issues with client and flink-streaming-java dependencies, then, streamer dependency is already included in clients dependency, so you can get rid of flink-streaming-java dependency. Even, without using Planner, flink-streaming-java dependency is included in clients.

Comment: @Alter Yes, you are right. After flink 1.11, flink-clients was exclude from flink-streaming-java dependency. So I add all this package when I develop and debug flink job in IDEA. And when deploy to online env, all of this package will be set to `provided` scope, for get rid of conflict between client and server version.

Comment: even for IDEA you really do not need them at all. You can put only clients dependency in your profile configuration for IDEA, it  should work

Answer (score 1):

For people encountering the same issue but are using gradle rather than Maven, its the same issue with the Flink-clients. You just need to add

```
compile "org.apache.flink:flink-clients_${scalaBinaryVersion}:${flinkVersion}"
```

or if you're shadowing dependencies line 129 from the Flink-training repo: https://github.com/apache/flink-training/blob/master/build.gradle#L129

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
By exploring the `flink-clients (pom.xml)` in https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-clients I'd realize that the `<artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>` and `<artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>` are already contained into the `flink-clients (pom.xml)`, so I'd remove those dependencies from my pom.xml and then it works in both places: IntelliJ and out-of-the-box.

I hope this works for some else with the same issue than me!

Answer (score 0):

I have face the same exception with

```java
2021-11-01 15:32:51,114 ERROR org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                      [] - Error while running the command.                                                                                                                                                                                         
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: No ExecutorFactory found to execute the application.                                                                                                                                                                        
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:366) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.12-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                                                                                                   
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:219) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.12-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                                                                                
        at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.12-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                                                                                                                   
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:812) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.12-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                                                                                                               
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:246) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.12-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                                                                                                                          
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1054) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.12-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                                                                                                                 
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1132) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.12-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                                                                                                              
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28) [flink-dist_2.12-1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.12-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                                                                                      
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1132) [flink-dist_2.12-1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.12-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                                                                                                                         
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ExecutorFactory found to execute the application.                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        at org.apache.flink.core.execution.DefaultExecutorServiceLoader.getExecutorFactory(DefaultExecutorServiceLoader.java:88) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.12-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                                                                      
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(ExecutionEnvironment.java:1043) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.12-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                                                                                                
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.executeAsync(ContextEnvironment.java:129) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.12-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                                                                                               
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:70) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.12-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                                                                                                     
        at org.apache.flink.examples.java.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:93) ~[?:?]                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_282]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_282]                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_282]                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_282]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:349) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.12-SNAPSHOT]
```

and that because I submit job with `flink run` ,rather than `flink run-application`,
while with param `--target=kubernetes-application`

Answer (score 0):

For flink version 1.15.1 we can use the following dependencies It will fix the problem.

```
<properties>
        <flink.version>1.15.1</flink.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```