# maven Failed to collect dependencies spark commons-code

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

Seeing maven build errors but I don't see `commons-codec:jar:1.15` in `jests3t` as a [dependency](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jets3t/jets3t/0.9.4/jets3t-0.9.4.pom).

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project XXXX: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:jar:2.3.3 -> net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.9.4 -> commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15-SNAPSHOT:
```

Maven version :
`Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)`

Note: same project build working with Maven 3.6.3 version

Comment: The following `jar:1.15-SNAPSHOT:` is very strange because using a SNAPSHOT versions is wrong except you are a committer ... apart from that I doubt that this is related to Maven 3.6.3 vs. Maven 3.8.1 ...

Comment: I think it may be possible due to the nature how maven resolves the dependecies 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740785/why-order-of-maven-dependencies-matter

Comment: Without the full project nor the full log output it's hard to even guess what causes the issue.

Comment: @vkt: Are you able to find any solution for this.  I am facing this error too and trying to fix it with no luck

Comment: we did some updates to spark version and also override dependencies.